# Semigroup homomorphism which isn't a monoid homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I am trying to find monoids $G$ and $H$ and a semigroup homomorphism $f:G\to H$ that is not a monoid homomorphism.

I know that I need $f(1_G)\neq 1_H$.

Is this a valid example:

$f:(\mathbb{Z},\times)\to (\mathbb{Z},\times)$, $f(x)=0$. In this example, $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for every $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$, but $f(1)\neq 1$.

The reason I'm not sure about this example is that the image of $f$ is $\{0\}$, so it seems like the group $H$ should just be the trivial group, instead of $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$.

Does my example work? Or if not, can someone give me a hint about how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the answers:

Any semigroup morphism $f:M\to S$ with $M$ a monoid, induces a monoid structure *on the image* $f(M)\subseteq S$, with $f(1)$ being its 'local' unit element. 
However, if $f$ is not surjective, $f(1)$ needs not be a unit in the whole semigroup $S$, as your example shows.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is correct.  The *image* of $f$ is $\{0\}$, but the codomain is $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$, and it's the codomain you use to determine whether it is a monoid homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is correct.
$0\colon (\mathbb{Z},\times)\to (\mathbb{Z}, \times)$
is a semigroup homomorphism but not a monoid homomorphism.

Observe that $\{0\}$ is not a submonoid of $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$. You could choose the codomain to be $(\{0,1\},\times)$, though.

Answer (score -1):

your example, can have a monoid homomorphism, because
\begin{align*}
1.f(x)=f(x)=f(1.x)=f(1).f(x) \qquad \forall x\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
Since $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ is cancelable, we have
\begin{align*}
1=f(1).
\end{align*}

Comment: how is $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ cancellable? it's just a PID, not a field, and even then cancellability only applies to non-zero elements, whereas $f$ maps everything to $0$